# ASP.NET MVC 2 Areas and route priority

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

Is it possible to set route priority in asp.net mvc 2 using arearegistration? I have a catch all {*pagePath} route which I want to set the lowest priority on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639971/mvc-2-arearegistration-routes-order

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, but Haacked's answer is incomplete. Please see my new response to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639971/mvc-2-arearegistration-routes-order/2107602#2107602

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, however it is only useful for sending things to the back of the stack (which is a good idea for your catch-all).

```
var route = routes["home_default"];
routes.Remove(route);
routes.Add(route);
```

I use this on my project with routes and it moves it to the end of the list.