# MVC3 Routing with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a MVC3 application with two areas and a root area.  The general structure looks like
Root

```
- Root/Areas/Manager
    * Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    * ManagerAreaRegistration.cs
- Root/Areas/Participant
    * Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    * ParticipantAreaRegistraion.cs
- Root
    * Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    * Views/Account/Register.cshtml
    * Global.asax.cs
```

I am having two problems with routing.  The first is that I am unable to navigate to any pages in the Root/Views folders except the one set as default in the Global.asax.cs file.  The Global.asax.cs file looks like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new {controller="Home" , action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
   new[] { "MVCApplication.Controllers" }    // for areas 
   );
...     
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
...
```

And the code in Root/Views/Home/Index.cshtml which is the start page looks like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Accounts","Register", new {area="", controller="Accounts"},null)
@Html.ActionLink("Manager", "Index", new { area = "Manager", controller = "Home" })
@Html.ActionLink("Participant", "Index", new { area = "Participant", controller = "Home" })
```

The two area links work fine as I have added routes into the registration files in each area, but the link to Accounts/Register which is another page in the root gives a 'resources not found error'.   However, if I change the Global.asax.cs route to have

```
    new {controller="Accounts" , action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
```

in the default route, then I can start on the Register page.

**So my first question is:**  How do I use routes to be able to access both pages in the Areas and in the Root (ie the Accounts/Register page)?

My second question has to do with the areas themselves.  Since they both have a 'Home' controller, I have put the area name in front of one to distinguish it, but I would like to not have to do this.  Currently the 'ParticipantAreaRegistration.cs file has the code:

```
  context.MapRoute(
            "Participant_default",
            "Participant/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new[] { "MvcApplication.Areas.Participant.Controllers"  }    // for areas 
            );
```

which gives URL's of "localhost****/Participant/Home"

while the ManagerAreaRegistraion.cs has code

```
 context.MapRoute(
            "Manager_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                         new[] { "MvcApplication.Areas.Manager.Controllers" }    // for areas 

        );
```

which gives URL's of "localhost***/Home/"

**My second question is :** How can I  have the URL of "localhost**/Home for both Manager and Participant (or for any number of areas) without having to have the Area name displayed in the URL?

I know this question is similar to others already on file, but I have scoured these to no avail and am currently drowning in inefficiency, so I thought I would try asking with specificity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use custom routing.
>
> Something similar to this one:
>
> [MVC 2 AreaRegistration Routes Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639971/mvc-2-arearegistration-routes-order/2107602#2107602)
>
> Using the solution in the above problem, you can write custom order of routing.
>
> In one of my application, I have areas named Admin,Blog,Members and
>   Public. I have routed the Public area as the url:
>   http://localhost:4000/, Admin as: http://localhost:4000/admin, blog
>   as: http://localhost:4000/blog, etc.. If you want my code, I can give
>   you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I know that it should work, but I haven't had success yet.  If you wouldn't mind sharing your code maybe that would help.  If you can zip it up and send it .. or just put the relevant snippets in an email, that would be cool. (aespaldi at gmail).